# Cannot acces rust struct fields

Tags: rust

I have a project where I have a struct that looks like this:

```
pub struct Msg1Sender {
    c_u: Vec<u8>,
    secret: StaticSecret,
    X_u: PublicKey,
    static_secret: EphemeralSecret,
    static_public: PublicKey,
    APPEUI : Eui64,
    kid: Vec<u8>,
    auth: [u8; 64], //remove
}
```

that is constructeed like this:

```
impl PartyU<Msg1Sender> {

    pub fn new(
        c_u: Vec<u8>,
        ecdh_secret: [u8; 32],
        stat_priv: EphemeralSecret,
        stat_pub: PublicKey,
        APPEUI : Eui64,
        kid: Vec<u8>,
    ) -> PartyU<Msg1Sender> {
        // From the secret bytes, create the DH secret
        let secret = StaticSecret::from(ecdh_secret);
        // and from that build the corresponding public key
        let X_u = PublicKey::from(&secret);
        // Combine the authentication key pair for convenience
 
        let mut auth = [0; 64];   //remove
        PartyU(Msg1Sender {
            c_u,
            secret,
            X_u,
            static_secret:stat_priv,
            static_public:stat_pub,
            APPEUI,
            kid,
            auth //slettes
        })
    }
    ...
```

and then I have the following code in another file:

```
let msg1_sender =
    PartyU::new(u_c_u, u_priv, v_static_priv, v_static_pub,APPEUI, u_kid);

    
println!("{:?}", msg1_sender.APPEUI);
```

Where I am trying to print a field on the struct.
This I can not do. I get the error:

```
no field `APPEUI` on type `oscore::edhoc::PartyU<oscore::edhoc::api::Msg1Sender>`

unknown field

help: one of the expressions' fields has a field of the same name: `0.`
```

Adding `pub` keywords to the fields I am trying to access makes no difference

Which makes no sense to me. the field exists. Why is this happening?

```
EDIT
```

I can now understand that the type I am trying to access is of type

```
PartyU<oscore::edhoc::api::Msg1Sender>
```

My mistake.
But If I now try to access the msgsender object by writing:

```
msg1_sender.0.APPEUI
```

It still fails with:

```
field `0` of struct `oscore::edhoc::PartyU` is private
```

Which again is strange to me, since the struct is public:

```
pub struct PartyU<S: PartyUState>(S);

// Necessary stuff for session types
pub trait PartyUState {}
impl PartyUState for Msg1Sender {}
impl PartyUState for Msg2Receiver {}
//impl PartyUState for Msg2Verifier {}
//impl PartyUState for Msg3Sender {}

/// Contains the state to build the first message.
pub struct Msg1Sender {
    c_u: Vec<u8>,
    secret: StaticSecret,
    x_u: PublicKey,
    static_secret: EphemeralSecret,
    static_public: PublicKey,
    pub APPEUI : Eui64,
    kid: Vec<u8>,
    auth: [u8; 64], //remove
}
impl PartyU<Msg1Sender> {
```

What part is it that I need to mark as public?

Comment: `msg1_sender` is not of type `Msg1Sender` but of type `PartyU<Msg1Sender>`. You don't show us how `PartyU` is defined so it's hard to say any more. [looking at the error message, it looks like it might be a tuple struct and `msg1_sender.0` having the type you expect.]

Comment: Why did you think that `PartyU` has this field? What is unclear to you about the "help" message?

Comment: thx, you were right. I still have an issue rgarding the acces. I added an edit

Comment: for the second part, you need to mark the fields you want to access as `pub` too. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod/struct_visibility.html

Comment: I've done that, still can't access the `0`

Answer (score 1):

`PartyU` is a struct tuple, so in order to access the inner struct you have to access with `.0`.

Then after that, the Error code is clear:

> field `0` of struct `oscore::edhoc::PartyU` is private

unless marked as `pub`, `struct` attributes are private and can only be accessed from the structs current module. You have to options to make them publicly available:

- `pub` makes it public for any scope
- `pub(crate)` makes it public for the crate where the struct lives in

```rust
pub struct PartyU(pub Msg1Sender);

pub struct Msg1Sender {
    pub c_u: Vec<u8>,
    pub secret: StaticSecret,
    pub X_u: PublicKey,
    pub static_secret: EphemeralSecret,
    pub static_public: PublicKey,
    pub APPEUI : Eui64,
    pub kid: Vec<u8>,
    pub auth: [u8; 64], //remove
}
```

Comment: the struct is marked with `pub` already. The attributes of the struct have all ben marked with pub `PartyU` is also marked with `pub`. Which thing specifically should be marked with pub?

Comment: @Grazosi, in your example your attributtes are not marked as pub, you need to mark them each.

Comment: yes, this I have done, which has had no effect

Comment: @Grazosi, check latest edit, `pub struct PartyU(pub Msg1Sender);` also needs.

Comment: hmm, I have no such line `pub struct PartyU(pub Msg1Sender);`

Comment: ah, you mean this one `pub struct PartyV<S: PartyVState>(pub S);` adding pub hwere, also has no effect